# How to determine the saturation level when an opamp schmitt trigger starts worknig?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, saturation, schmitt-trigger, multivibrator

The Opamp inverting schmitt trigger is constructed as shown.

[image: An inverting schmitt trigger]

The output signal is:

[image: The Output Signal of an inverting schmitt trigger]

So I ask why is the output at the start of operation saturated to positive?

Also, if the input voltage is moved from the negative to positive terminal the starting output will saturate to negative. Why?

Is there a rule to follow? If so, what causes this rule?

What will happen if R1 is replaced with a capacitor, as in a monostable multivibrator?
What will be its starting saturation level that will charge the capacitor. What will be the UTP and LTP then?

Comment: There seems to be a legitimate question in there, but there writing is incomprehensible.  Closing until we get something written in English.

Comment: Sorry about that, but the question is quite fuzzy by nature. What determines  the saturation level of a Schmitt Trigger at the beginning of its operation when the input is between UTP and LTP

Comment: @RaafatAbualazm, see the comment in my answer

Comment: One question per question, please! If the input is moved to positive terminal or R1 is replaced by a cap, it will not be a Schmitt trigger anymore.

Comment: Oh  sorry! But I have a test tomorrow and the professor and the section guy don't understand the circuit.

Comment: What would it be then?

Comment: You have a test tomorrow and the professor doesn't understand the circuit? How can he give you a test then?

Comment: Well, in Egypt everything is possible.

Answer (score 3):

The Schmitt trigger works similar to a comparator, so imagine you have a comparator with a Vref in the non inverting input. When the input voltage falls below that threshold, the output of the comparator saturates high. If the input voltage then goes above the threshold, the output goes low. If you were to put the Vref into the non inverting input, the same rule applies, but backwards, so when the input goes below the threshold, the output goes low, and if it then goes above, the output goes high.

The general rule is if the non inverting input is *less than* the inverting input, the output will be high.

The Schmitt trigger works in almost the same way, except it has upper and lower limits. As you can see from your diagram, the input voltage (sine wave) starts at 0, which means the inverting input is *lower than* the non inverting, hence the output starts high. Once it goes above the high threshold, the output goes low. With a Schmitt trigger, the output will stay low untill the lower threshold is met.

As with the comparator, if you were to swap the input voltage to the non inverting input, it would be the other way round.

I believe this is what you were asking, but please correct me if I am wrong as the English was rather poor, as Olin pointed out.

Comment: Well we have two refrences, the postive and tge negative.

Comment: Why should yhen we start with the positive reference? May be 0 is less than the positive one, but it might have been a negative reference in the beginning.  If 0 is more than the negative level then it should saturate at the negative level.

Comment: Yes, that is how the Schmitt trigger works. Look at the output compared to the input sine wave. It works the same as I describes, when the input goes *above* the upper threshold, the output swings low, and when it is *below* the lower threshold, the output swings high

Comment: You don't have 2 'references', you have a high and low threshold. As for why the output starts high when the input starts in between the 2 threshold levels, that is just for ease of showing how the circuit works. It's not an oscilloscope screenshot. They have to show the operation of a circuit, and when doing this, a sine wave will usually start at 0. As it is below the upper threshold, it would not make sense to have it 'indetermined' in a circuit example, so they show it high (as it would normally be at that point mid operation).

Comment: I am asking about the beginning of the operation , at t = 0 and the input is between UTP and LTP what should be my reference? Positive or negative saturation level.

Comment: See my second comment. This is an example circuit, showing an example wave form. it is going to try and help you understand the operation of the circuit, not try and confuse the user more by going into incredible detail about startup etc

Comment: It would be like someone showing a simple resistive circuit and giving the resistor a value and you asking 'why is the resistor exactly 10 ohms when there is an ambient temperature, heat dissipation and resistive tolerance?'. It just doesn't need to be gone into with an example to help someone understand the theoretical working of a circuit

Comment: And a point to clarify, did you mean in the "General rule" that the output is to be low?

Comment: The general rule of a comparator is: If the inverting input is lower than the non inverting input, the output will be high. Use that same rule for the Schmitt trigger, but in terms of the high and low threshold.

Comment: I hope I have been able to now answer your queries?

Comment: To a great extent yes.

Comment: Thanks, but onelast question. What happens if a Capacitor is put instead of the resistor?

Comment: It should just change the output waveform to more of a triangle or sawtooth wave

Answer (score 3):

> How to determine the saturation level when an opamp schmitt trigger
>   starts workig?

With the "theoretical" circuit you have shown and the input at 0 volts, upon power being applied, there is no real way to determine what the output state will be. The output anomaly will resolve itself when the input signal passes one of the two thresholds. Once this has resolved, the output is unambiguous.

Many applications will want the output to be unambiguous at power-up (in the absense of a significant input signal) and circuit measures can be taken to force a high or low situation at the output but, on a simple theoretical circuit like the one shown, it is impossible to determine.

Comment: Then how to force it to become undeterminate?

Comment: If you want to force it to be indetermined, keep it below the thresholds

Comment: @RaafatAbualazm I'm not sure your original comment made sense - forcing something to be undeterminate doesn't mean anything sensible. Forcing something to be determinate does. As MCG comments, keep it below the thresholds continues keeping it undeterminate but I don't think this is what you are asking about. I think you are asking how to make the output unambiguously high or low at power-up. To do this you can use a capacitor to the negative rail from the non-inverting input to keep the output low or, a cap from pos rail to keep the output high at power-up.

Comment: That I meant. Sorry, I'm having hard times these days. But what happens if I replace a resistor with a capacitor in the postive feedback loop.

Comment: Oh.... yeah sorry, I must have read that differently!

Comment: You can put capacitors in the feedback loop but seriously, if you want to try this either download LTSpice or student edition of micro-cap 11 - the latter is my preferred choice of simulator and you can try these things out and get a better definitive feel for things.

Comment: I have proteus, but in anything Analog it is Garbage really. Gonnna try your suggested software, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of theory, we assume an initial state of output.

Here in your circuit for inverting schmitt trigger, it is assumed to be \$+V_{sat}.R_2/(R_1+R_2)\$ at the non-inverting terminal, at t= 0, and the circuit waveforms are analysed.

Even if you assume it to be \$-V_{sat}.R_2/(R_1+R_2)\$ at t =0, you will eventually end up in the same waveform, as the outputs are resolved itself. The same happens in real circuits too.

Comment: How is the output to resolve , please?

Comment: Instead of +Vsat, assume -Vsat at Vo for t= 0. It will still resolve automatically to the required waveform of the figure. You can draw the corresponding waveforms and prove it yourself.

Comment: So the point is...initial state you can assume of your choice.

Comment: It doesn't really matter

Comment: It will resolve but after a cycle or so. Not instantly, I thought It'd be in an instant

Comment: Yes after a cycle.